# Compactness of a distribution

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I calculate the input to a box and whisker diagram like this (`data` is a sorted integer array), and `LQ`,  `UQ` are the lower resp. upper quantile:

```
    Min:    data[0],
    LQ:     data[len(data)/4],
    Median: data[len(data)/2],
    UQ:     data[len(data)/4*3],
    Max:    data[len(data)-1],
```

My question would be: Is there a mathematical definition / algorithm to define how 'compact' such an array of integers is? If Max-Min = 0 it's super compact, but what would a sane definition of compactness / heterogeneity be if I compare two such arrays and for both holds `Max - Min != 0` ?

Normal distribution of `data` is assumed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [coefficient of variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation#Estimation) (CV) to compare the homogeneity/ variability between two data sets. The CV is given by $$CV=\frac{s}{\bar{x}}$$ where $s$ denotes the standard deviation of the sample and $\bar{x}$ the mean of the sample. The $CV$ is measured in percent units, which is means that is a number (free of specific measurement units) and can be used for comparison between different data sets. Sets with values of CV less than $10\%$ tend to be interpreted as homogenous sets.

In the example you mention, i.e. when $\max -\min=0$ then the CV will also be zero and that is also the only case in which the CV will be zero.